# Is there a way to duplicate a dictionary key and attach different values to those keys?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am looking to make a dictionary that lists "Quantity" as the Key and an integer for the value. However, what I also need to do is get "Quantity" to repeat itself and add the values in the sequence of the list that I am using to supply the values.

What I did already was use the dict(zip) function while using 'Quantity' in a list and the values in a list but that only gives me one result when I need multiple (as many that are elements in my values list). I'm also trying a for loop but perhaps my syntax is just wrong. Here is a look at what I've done thus far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
fd = []

html = '''<input id="qty_cartline_change_-1313013247" class="qty" type="text" name="qty" value="1" maxlength="4" data-component="quantitybox.value" data-productdata-name="quantity">
<input id="qty_cartline_change_112550273" class="qty" type="text" name="qty" value="1" maxlength="4" data-component="quantitybox.value" data-productdata-name="quantity">
<input id="qty_cartline_change_112551625" class="qty" type="text" name="qty" value="6" maxlength="4" data-component="quantitybox.value" data-productdata-name="quantity">
<input id="qty_cartline_change_112559375" class="qty" type="text" name="qty" value="2" maxlength="4" data-component="quantitybox.value" data-productdata-name="quantity">
<input id="qty_cartline_change_112550126" class="qty" type="text" name="qty" value="5" maxlength="4" data-component="quantitybox.value" data-productdata-name="quantity">

quantity = ['Quantity']
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
values = [item['value'] for item in soup.select("input[value]")]
d = dict(zip(quantity, values))
print(d)
```

The result for that is as follows:

```
{'Quantity': '1'}
```

That's a step in the right direction but I need the results to look like this:

```
{'Quantity': '1'}
{'Quantity' : '1'}
{'Quantity' : '6'}
{'Quantity' : '2'}
{'Quantity' : '5'}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Well, to be clear *you can have at most one value for each key in a dictionary*. To solve your problem though, you could have a list of dictionaries or perhaps a dictionary where instead of the key `Quantity` it is the ID of the HTML element. The smallest change would be a list of dictionaries and it would look like

```py
values = ...  # same as before
dicts = [{'Quantity': v} for v in values]
```

Comment: This solution worked and definitely helped me out. Thank you, brother.